# show that the ways to pick 2 subsets A and B of [n] when A is subset of B equals to n^3

Tags: combinations

I know that the total of subsets of a set is 2^n.
I am assuming I have to use combinations but I cannot think of something to start.
Anybody can help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write your questions.

Comment: BTW, the answer is not $n^3$, as the title say, is $3^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each element of $[n]$ you have $3$ choices:

- Put it in $A$ (so necessarily also in $B$).
- Put it in $B$ but not in $A$.
- Don't put it in $A$ nor $B$.